# Get Count of first records in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

When user pay for his product, I add a payment record to PaymentTBL, Now I want to know count of all first payments per month.
I built this query :

```
   SELECT Count(*) as OptIn, Month(StartDate) As MonthNum, Year(StartDate) As YearNum
  FROM [dietdb].[dbo].[PaymentsTBL]

  group by Month(StartDate), Year(StartDate)
```

But it doesn't give me what I want exactly, because I need to know only those who start with app in this month and not those who reoccurring/renew their payments.

Is there any good way to achieve this?

Below is the PaymentTBL structure :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PaymentsTBL](
    [AutoNo] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PersonID] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [UDID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [StartDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Duration] [float] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_PaymentsTBL_Duration]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [EndDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Points] [float] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_PaymentsTBL_Points]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [Cost] [float] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_PaymentsTBL_Cost]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [Currency] [int] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_PaymentsTBL_Currency]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [TypeID] [int] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_PaymentsTBL_TypeID]  DEFAULT ((2)),
    [IsActive] [bit] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_PaymentsTBL_IsActive]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [InsertDate] [datetime] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_PaymentsTBL_InsertDate]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [InsertUser] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [UpdateDate] [datetime] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_PaymentsTBL_UpdateDate]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [UpdateUser] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [PayBy] [int] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_PaymentsTBL_PayBy]  DEFAULT ((1)),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PaymentsTBL] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [AutoNo] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Sample of Data that I need :

```
OptIn   MonthNo YearNo
47  1   2015
56  2   2015
72  3   2015
61  4   2015
74  5   2015
43  6   2015
154 7   2015
180 8   2015
190 9   2015
139 10  2015
169 11  2015
117 12  2015
147 1   2016
137 2   2016
135 3   2016
154 4   2016
141 5   2016
109 6   2016
162 7   2016
75  8   2016
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data, end the expected result!

Comment: Yes, I added the structure of table

Comment: Show us some sample table data

Comment: So you simply want each year/month's number of rows?

Comment: Does "count of all first payments per month" mean "if a person has at least one payment per month, count them only once"? If so a distinct count does what you need

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid No, I mean the first payment for person among all his payments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT Count(*) as OptIn, Month(StartDate) As MonthNum, Year(StartDate) As YearNum FROM
(
select PersonID, min(startdate) as startdate FROM [dietdb].[dbo].[PaymentsTBL]
group by PersonID
) as t
group by Month(StartDate), Year(StartDate)
```

Comment: It seems you got what I mean, But Please check your query it has syntax error. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'on'.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use row_number() to determine a person's first payment, then count those per month, like this:

```
select
       Month(StartDate) MonthNo
     , Year(StartDate) YearNo
     , count(case when rn = 1 then 1 end) as OptIn
     , count(*) as count_all
from (
    select
      *
      , row_number() over(partition by PersonID order by StartDate) as rn
     from PaymentsTBL
    ) d
group by
       Month(StartDate) 
     , Year(StartDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query:-

```
SELECT Count(*) as OptIn, Month(StartDate) As MonthNum, Year(StartDate) As YearNum
FROM [dietdb].[dbo].[PaymentsTBL]
WHERE Month(StartDate) = MONTH(GETDATE())
AND Year(StartDate) = YEAR(GETDATE())
group by Month(StartDate), Year(StartDate)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want record of first payment in every month.

id column is primary key of table

```
SELECT min(id) as OptIn, Month(StartDate) As MonthNum, Year(StartDate) As YearNum
FROM [dietdb].[dbo].[PaymentsTBL]
group by Month(StartDate), Year(StartDate)
```